# Pro and contra - angular or xamarin for a scalable web application

Tags: angular, xamarin, web-applications

I'd like to try a webapplication hosted on a server, my projects so far have been running locally on my machine, so I just read a little bit about how best practice is.
I am now faced with the choice, Angular or Xamarin. React and Vue.js I personally excluded for myself after I've dealt with something. In addition, I would like to keep the field quite small because a comparison of the frameworks or libraries is usually rated as very user-oriented.

I find the component approach of Angular very good in terms of maintainability, reusability and testability.
Likewise, I find the clear separation of HTML, CSS and JavaScript or TypeScript very good.
Since I already have contact with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, I can say that I enjoy working with it a lot.

I can not find a comparison between Xamarin and Angular etc. Angular is usually compared to React or Vue.js. Therefore I would be glad about some information. Best if you have experience from both environments.
The whole thing should be future-proof, have good support or a strong community, be scalable and run on different clients.
In the aftermath is to consider whether the communication should run on rest or soap. But this is a separate topic.

Comment: Xamarin is not a web framework

Comment: Thanks for your constructive contribution and your 0 error tolerance

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin is not a Web Framework therefore, you cannot compare it to Angular, Vue or similar, that is why you cannot find any information about it.

Xamarin is for creating mobile applications for iOS, Android and Windows using C# and .NET to support this process.

If your project is web-based, then go for Angular or Vue. However, if you are planning to develop a **NATIVE mobile app**, then go for Xamarin.

Comment: Thank you for your description.
However, I have seen some projects where people have used Xamarin to build web applications to serve them only on the desktop via a browser.
Can you describe from your personal experience why you would prefer to use Angular instead of Xamarin?

Comment: Xamarin is not for web, Angular is for web, so if you are building a web app go for Angular otherwise choose Xamarin for mobile. Xamarin was never meant to be used for web simple.